# How can I make a hta iframe 100% height?

Tags: html, hta

I'm attempting to run this iframe in HTA, but although I put the height as 100%, it's only showing up as about 30% for some reason. I'm new to HTA but it's mostly the same as HTML. How can this work? Thanks in advance ~

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<title> Test iframe </title>
<head>
<iframe src="http://cyberh1.xyz/paste/index2.php" style="border:1px blue solid;" name="frame1" scrolling="auto" frameborder="yes" align="center" height = "100%" width = "100%">
</iframe>
 </head>
```

[image: Screenshot]

Comment: You are missing `<body>` tags. All displayed content on the page should be contained in it.

Answer (score 1):

You would need to set the `html`, `body` and `iframe` to have a width and height of 100%:

```
<style>
html,
body,
iframe {
width: 100%;
height: 100%;
}
</style>
```

Like @Terry said though, you are missing the `body` which the iframe should be within.

Comment: Awesome that worked! Thank you very very much :)